# When will the 2017 developer survey results be posted?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2017

I've googled this question and only ran across links leading me to take the (now closed) developer survey.

When will the results for the 2017 developer survey be posted?

Comment: Last year they weren't published until mid-March.

Comment: [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26491/can-someone-let-me-in-on-the-6-8-weeks-joke)

Comment: I'm looking forward to see the question "When will the 2023 developer survey results be posted?", with a link to the same question for 2022, from there to 2021.... tracing back to this one (which already links to 2016 and beyond) - and each year's answer decorated with a 6-8-weeks-link....

Comment: They're up now: http://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/

Comment: WOW. I can't believe my question from over 3 years ago was closed because of a new question posted less than 12 hours ago. It's like you expect me to have a time machine to know these questions were to be posted!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The current plan is to release the results on March 15. We're in the process of analyzing the results now and then will scrub the data of PII so we can share with the community. We'll keep you posted if this timeline changes!

**Update:** We pushed the timeline back a week to account for some additional analysis and translation work. We'll go live with the results on Wednesday, March 22.

Comment: I wish this question had been asked 2-4 weeks ago.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes so it could be answered in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @Felix well, so the answer would have been "in 6-8 weeks", but basically yeah

Comment: I can't wait...

Comment: What does PII mean?

Comment: @nwp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information

Comment: its March 17 already.... :(

Comment: 21 March, one more day.

Comment: ...and we're live!!! \o/

Comment: When will the data become available for download with ODbL licensing?