# When will the 2018 Developer Survey results be ready?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

When will the 2018 Developer Survey results be ready?

It was closed on [January 29th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362586/when-is-the-2018-developer-survey-closing) and there is no information about the results. How long will It take to prepare them?

Comment: [Last year it was March 22](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344102/1835379)

Comment: In about 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: In most time, if the question start with "When" in SO meta, answer is 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The results will be released on March 13th.

Answer (score 30):

You can find the tags for the surveys here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/survey/info

Dates of publishing so far have been:

- [2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/11/survey-says/): January 11, 2011
- [2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/10/survey-results/): February 10, 2012
- [2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/25/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/): January 25, 2013
- [2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/19/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/): February 19, 2014
- [2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/07/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2015-the-results/): April 7, 2015
- [2016](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2016): [March 17, 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319191/1391441)
- [2017](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017): [March 22, 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344102/1391441)
- [2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018): [March 5, 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364150)
- [2019](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019): [April 2, 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382367)

An average gives ~44 days starting from January 11 which points to the first days of March. Based on the last two years only, it'll be around March 20.

We should start making bets :P

Comment: Is it too late to bet on March 13th? :P

Comment: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/