# When will the 2019 developer survey results be posted?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2019

I can find the tags for the surveys here:

Dates of publishing so far have been:

- 2010: January 11, 2011
- 2011: February 10, 2012
- 2012: January 25, 2013
- 2013: February 19, 2014
- 2015: April 7, 2015
- 2016: March 17, 2016
- 2017: March 22, 2017

When will the 2019 developer survey results be posted?

Comment: I disagree with those suggesting to close this question.  While it may not be the greatest question, it's certainly not too broad and not opinion based.  There are people here that work at SO that may be able to answer this question satisfactorily.

Comment: ["The survey will be open until February 12,"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379281/7795130) so not before then.

Comment: It will take us some weeks to analyze the data, build the results page, etc. We don't have a firm launch date yet, but will announce it on all of our promotional channels (blog, Meta, top banner, email, etc.) when the results are ready.

Comment: *and not opinion based* @AleksG I'm guessing the justification for "opinion based" is that since a definitive answer isn't actually possible, not even by an employee, any answer would be a guess. OP, I think this would have been better received if you'd waited a while after the survey closed to ask it. That way they'd at least know how much data they have to go through.

Comment: Trust me, it will take **6 to 8 weeks** once survey completed.

Comment: Any dates announced for the result?

Comment: Surely by the end of the year

Comment: @Div That is to say, April 8, 2019?

Comment: @AnitaTaylor It should be analyzed by now.

Comment: Is the text in this question copied/pasted from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362941/1364007)? Seems very similar, and it's weird that this question doesn't mention 2018 (the answer didn't either as it was before the 2018 results were published).

Comment: @rene Why mark my question as duplicate? This question is old than one year but you mention the question is new one.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which way we duplicate vote.I don't think we need a new question for every year, so I picked the most recent one, gathered the relevant info from several answers and dupe voted all the other questions against a single canonical. I think this makes finding and updating this information much easier, now and in the future. Feel free to raise an issue on Meta if you have strong arguments why this should be reversed / handled differently.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The survey results are live!

- [View the results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019)
- [View the announcement on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382647/1364007)

Comment: Can't wait to see the results.

Comment: are there any delays with that? Do you have some insight when the results are going to be released? (very eager to see them!)

Comment: Do you have any prevision when the full dataset will become available for download here ? https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey

Comment: @anvd [mid-to-late May](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382647/1364007).