# 2019 Developer Survey results are live

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2019, announcement

Thank you to everyone — nearly 90,000 developers from around the world — who took [this year's survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey).

[View the results >>](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019)

Some of this year’s key findings:

- Python, the fastest-growing major programming language, has risen in the ranks of programming languages in our survey yet again, edging out Java this year and standing as the second most loved language (behind Rust).
- Over half of respondents had written their first line of code by the time they were sixteen, although this experience varies by country and by gender.
- We asked respondents to think about the last time they solved coding problems with and without our site. The data indicates that Stack Overflow saves a developer 30 to 90 minutes of time per week!

The anonymized survey results are available under the Open Database License, allowing you to download and analyze the dataset. Certain survey answers are treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore excluded from the anonymized results. [Download the .csv file](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/)

Comment: I am impressed by the number of people with 50+ years of experience, and wasn't expecting it to be that high.

Comment: "I am unable to / find it difficult to type - 0.3%"  It would be interesting next year to ask about the number of developers who _could_ type (that is, who have the use of all ten fingers) but _don't_.  I'm continually amazed at the number of people who code for a living but never bothered to learn ten-finger typing, and who do all their coding with two or four fingers.

Comment: Curiously, the write-up about "Will People Born Today Have a Better Life Than Their Parents?" talked about it being a measure of optimism.  I'm not sure that follows.  If you answered "No," it doesn't necessarily mean you think things will be _worse_ for people born today than for their parents.  It could just mean they think things will stay roughly the same.  I wouldn't call that a lack of optimism.  Maybe in Western Europe, for instance, conditions are good enough that people don't feel the need for things to improve?

Comment: *"This year 11% of US survey respondents are women, up from 9% on last year's survey."* Phew, thank god -- the Welcome Wagon wasn't in vain.

Comment: Languages associated with higher salaries...  It would be interesting to see how it correlates with job titles.  F# commands quite high salaries, for instance...but is that due to F# itself, or is it because the types of jobs in which F# is used happen to be much higher-paying than "average coder" jobs?  It seems to me likely that the type of job is more relevant to salary than the language, and that the language follows from the job type.

Comment: I have never heard of `Rust` yet the community selected as the "most loved programming language"

Comment: "This is especially notable in countries like France and Germany, which are the 4th and 7th largest economies in the world, respectively." this implies France's economy is bigger than Germany, which it is certainly not. Rephrasing as "This is especially notable in countries like Germany and France, which are the 4th and 7th largest economies in the world, respectively." would be preferable IMO

Comment: @RyanLundy and it needs a breakdown or correction for average income per country in case of the global figures. Here in Switzerland the average salary is a lot higher than the average in India for example. In case this correction has already been done it should be mentioned.

Comment: I noticed that the results use "three-fourths" as opposed to (what sounds more natural to me) "three-quarters". [Google's NGram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) says that the term "three fourths" is used about [one fourth as often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+fourths%2Cthree+quarters&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthree%20fourths%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20quarters%3B%2Cc0) as "three quarters". Neither [is more correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103188/109567), though.

Comment: "Germany has an unusually high proportion of developers working part-time."  In Germany, Switzerland, and perhaps other places in Europe, one can work in percentages.  For instance, many developers in my office work 80%, which means they work 80% of the hours (here in Switzerland, 33.6 hours instead of a full 42) and take home 80% of a standard salary.  These respondents are probably included in the count of part-time.  Even a 90% worker might well consider him/herself part-time.

Comment: Why are so many results and categories based on gender? That really bothers me. Some fields of work have more women in them, some have more men, it's natural. I dislike this forceful display of "Look guys more women are active than last year, we're doing good!".

Comment: I'm not surprised that a lot of academic researchers are actively looking for jobs, as a PhD candidate, and most Post-Doc positions as well, are fixed-term (couple of years usually), with possibly students thrown in the mix as well. Meaning they'll *have* to move after their project/time/contract expires.

Comment: Is VBA really that much of a "dreaded" language? I feel like "Dread" <> "Not interested in continuing use". Strange word choice...

Comment: I'm surprised at how many transgender-identifying people responded to the survey. 1.2% is a really high percentage for that demographic.

Comment: I half-think we should ask for W-2 uploads next year; seems like a lot of people are fibbing their salaries by a wide margin, at least in the US. I mean, academic researchers drawing in a $95k salary as a median? Or maybe there's just one or two people making half a million dollars in that field somewhere that skewed the results way up (so maybe we should throw out the outliers and use the mean, instead?)

Comment: @SombreroChicken You think it's "natural" that the field of programming has more men or women? Considering you just need a brain and an input method, I don't think there's anything natural about a large imbalance in either direction. And given the worldwide movement over the last several decades of increasing equality in the workplace and on the internet, I think it should be obvious why there's a focus on weighing results based on gender.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah I do. Whatever the reason is that more men are interested in this field vs women is, it shouldn't really matter. There are other fields where it's the other way around but yet we don't see initiatives in those fields to balance this inequality. And why should there be? It's not a bad thing. Gender shouldn't even matter in the first place. I think trying to "balance" gender inequality in a field just for the sake of balancing is stupid. (Of course I'm only talking about balancing the number of people in a particular field here, salary(etc..) equality is very much a good thing)

Comment: @SombreroChicken "Whatever the reason is that more men are interested in this field vs women is, it shouldn't really matter". The reason could definitely matter. I actually can't think of a reason that wouldn't matter. It is not about artificially forcing a 50/50 men to women ratio. Its about asking *why* more women aren't interested in programming to begin with. If gender truly did not matter, wouldn't we have nearly 50/50 men to women across most fields?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic You misread, "gender shouldn't even matter in the first place" as in there shouldn't be such a focus on the issue.

Comment: Exactly, thank you @Passerby for explaining.

Comment: I was disappointed in the layout of the "Developer Role and Gender" chart. It explains that "developer types above the line have respondents that are more likely than average to be men". Making those jobs look above average? I'd rather see those below the line: needs improvement.

Comment: @TylerH or they could have included the project incentives, which are income.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Then you misunderstand the issue. It's not about whether one gender is more interested on average than another in programming. The numbers in the industry routinely do not match the response from asking individuals. This is the reason there is a focus on it, because checking yourself on occasion to make sure you're not being inadvertently or unnecessarily discriminatory is the morally and socially responsible thing to do. Remember, [privilege is invisible](https://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/2016/jun/08/workplace-gender-equality-invisible-privilege).

Comment: I'm genuinely curious why people are downvoting this. Do they not like the key findings that have been selected? Kind of comical

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382705/what-is-with-thanks-in-the-developer-perspectives-by-gender?noredirect=1#comment686650_382705 I'd love some insight into the developers' perspective as per my question @JuliaSilge

Comment: @dwirony good question - especially given VBA scored better than VB.NET last year, where VB6 held the "most dreaded" position. I find it very curious that neither VB6 nor VB.NET are even in the dread-list this year, as if everything VB* had been lumped together under "VBA", which is obviously terribly wrong, but apparently they didn't lump anything together, or so I was told. I wrote [What's Wrong With VBA?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/04/10/whats-wrong-with-vba/) in response to that unexpected 4-positions increase in VBA's dreadfulness.

Comment: @pushkin probably the downvoters are Java developers xD.

Answer (score 26):

I believe this issue was brought up when the blogpost about being more welcoming was posted, but I'd like to bring this up again.

There is a section: [Do Developers Consider Themselves Part of the Stack Overflow Community?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#community-_-do-developers-consider-themselves-part-of-the-stack-overflow-community):

[image]

We can clearly see that fewer women consider themselves to be a part of the community than men, and the paragraph below concludes:

> The tech community as a whole, and we at Stack Overflow in particular, still have work to do in this area.

However, before jumping to that conclusion, we must first ask **why** do developers not consider themselves to be a part of the community?

Is it because:

**1. the community is doing something to actively push them away?** Or

**2. they don't want to be a part of the community**

---

I believe that when the whole Welcoming controversy hit Meta, a woman posted an answer saying that she didn't consider herself to be a part of the community, because she (paraphrasing) has a life and doesn't want to invest that much into an Internet thingy like SO.

I feel that before jumping to the conclusion that we need to do something to make women feel like they're a part of the community, we need to first learn if they actually want to be.

Maybe next year's survey could have a follow-up "Why?" question where they can check one of several options:

- don't want to be
- want to be, but am being pushed away
- etc.

Just a thought.

Comment: Note that, cannot remember which year's, *why* has been asked before, not sure why they took it out this year. Perhaps they didn't like knowing that women generally didn't want to/need to feel a part of the community as you wrote

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Huh, well that is most suspicious. Thanks for sharing

Comment: While we may never know the exact reason, from the "Developer Insights" section asking about what you would change about StackOverflow, the overwhelmingly most common word in responses from women was "Condescending". Other common words included, "rude", "asshole", and "replies". I don't think that is something that should be dismissed.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic I agree that we shouldn't dismiss that. However, we cannot conclude what was concluded from the results of the survey question I linked to. We need to be responsible and dig a little deeper.

Comment: @pushkin The conclusion is just that "we have work to do in this area". Given the context of the recent welcoming push it may be implied that the work is to be nicer, but even if the results show that women "just don't want to" be part of the community, I doubt stack overflow as a company is fine with just ignoring such a large portion of the potential user base. We want more people to join the stack overflow community and programming in general. What can we and stack overflow be doing differently to make more people share an interest in our field?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Like I said, the conclusion is erroneous if it's drawn from that specific question (and I assume it was, since the conclusion appears in the paragraph summarizing the results of the question above it). Regarding *even if the results show that women "just don't want to" be part of the community, I doubt stack overflow as a company is fine with just ignoring such a large portion of the potential user base.*, if most women don't want to be part of the community, then "ignoring" them is the only thing to do. Or more appropriately, there *is* nothing to do (in that area)

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Note, I'm not saying that there *aren't* problems. I just take issue with that the conclusion since it was apparently drawn erroneously.

Comment: Although I think it's a good idea to try and be more inclusive to everyone. I'm also wondering why it seems like *most*  of the focus is on making more women/non-binary/etc feel like they are part of the community. 50% of men also don't feel like this. (which is *40k people*). Are we just not bothering with them because they are a majority? that seems like a *massive* amount of people to not focus on, just because they arn't of a minority.

Comment: @remy_rm Yes, that's another good point. Chuckled a little when I saw that

Comment: @remy_rm Because our field has a history of being heavily weighted towards favoring men and has only recently started seeing changes in that regard. In my opinion there are still plenty of not so subtle biases such as suggesting that women who don't feel part of the community just don't want to participate and should be left alone while simultaneously suggesting that we are not doing enough to reach out to men who don't feel included.

Comment: Personally, I really feel [the penultimate graph](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#community-_-developers-perspectives-by-gender) speaks for itself, and paints an unfortunate picture of SO (and, by extension, IT in general.)

Comment: @miken32 But what does it really say? That women are more likely to be targets of condescension whereas men are more likely to be targets of force? That women are more likely to suggest social solutions whereas men are more likely to suggest technical ones? Something else entirely? We can build whatever narrative we want, but I don't think we can draw any valid conclusions without further (deeper, more rigorous) research.

Answer (score 22):

The [Evaluating Competence](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#evaluating-competence) section shows that almost 70% of people who took this survey say they're above average developers.

Maybe this just means that most developers who use StackOverflow *are* in fact above-average developers... compared to those other plebs >.<

Comment: Or respondents to the survey are of the impression that if they are capable of answering most any question in their tags on the front page they are above average.

Comment: Whether they're more competent or not, I certainly agree that it is not safe to assume that Stack Overflow survey respondents are a representative sample of the broader developer population.

Comment: were they using the mean, median or mode though?

Comment: That means that 30% of developers aren't aware that [they're above average too!](https://assets.amuniversal.com/e74cc9402de901300872001dd8b71c47)

Comment: Regarding the usage of Stack Overflow and whether it makes devs above average or not, I would say it might (if you actively read posts about your field a lot); I really haven't yet found anyone offline that has the seemingly encyclopedic language feature knowledge / language specs that a lot of SO contributors have. As for me personally, I get the feeling that I am a lot nerdier than most other developers I've met IRL, I reference things from my book collection / papers I've read but almost nobody picks up on the reference (e.g., I only knew one other dev who knew Uncle Bob).

Comment: Honestly, the question is kind of meaningless, but I am really amused by the conclusion that junior developers *not* thinking of themselves as above average is evidence of imposter syndrome.

Comment: @rjzii meaningless indeed; it's generally pretty silly to try to rate how well you think you stand against other programmers (In your area? In the same field? In any field / fields you don't even know? What time frame, are we talking since the first mainframe?). There's different skillsets and I have yet to find an "easy" job...  and what even is programming performance? Speed of completion of a project? What if it was held up by something unrelated? How do you rank difficulty of projects? Etc, etc

Comment: Also, slight tangent, but IMO (as a coder) as far as the whole "ranking" thing goes, the only 'skill' metric that's worth caring about is whether you know how to do things you're interested in, the rest of the stuff kinda sounds like management material; if management is your passion, great, but if it isn't, I'd say you shouldn't confuse competition with what really motivates you ([obligatory Jackson Browne reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq25ZJwZJzU)). If you have a job and you like it that's all that matters.

Answer (score 16):

This result is confusing.

> [image]

WebAssembly doesn't belong in this category. Even more than conventional machine assembly, WebAssembly really isn't a language that anybody is writing directly. It's a compile target. The number of people who manually write `.wat` files (WebAssembly text encoding) by hand is unlikely to be much greater than one hundred people in the entire world, yet your results indicate that more than one thousand respondents of this survey selected in to this group. That is difficult to rationalize.

Comment: Plenty of people write conventional machine assembly code, and while you might not imagine how anyone could love doing so, I certainly could. In fact, I'd put myself in that category. I really have no idea what WebAssembly is, so that may be altogether different.

Comment: @CodyGray I believe you and acknowledge that there are many cases where it is still appropriate to hand-write conventional assembly code, perhaps to take full advantage of some hardware. I think this is less true for Wasm. Wasm is more like a low-level bytecode: not enough abstraction to be friendly for a human, but not close enough to the hardware to provide as much power as conventional assembly, and already with *many* different interpreters with different optimization characteristics. There are *some* cases for hand-writing it, and probably slightly more over time, but I think it's rare.

Comment: Wat. I seriously doubt that WebAssembly was voted here by people who write .wat files by hand. It is more reasonable to assume that developers who have had WebAssembly as a _build target_ are very likely to continue doing so.

Comment: @E_net4 that's fine, and beliveable, but that makes WASM distinct from every other "language" in this category, and meaningless to compare with them. I am excited about the ability to continue to target wasm, but I sure didn't identify as someone who writes wasm any more than I identify as someone who writes llvm bytecode, x64 machine code, or Python bytecode. They're not languages to me, they're targets.

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

When switching between tabs (e.g. Survey Respondents, Monthly Stack Overflow Visits, and Professional Developers) to compare results it's difficult to see what the differences are because the graphs fade out and in. Could you remove the `fade` class from all the `tab-pane`s, so that it's easy to compare the different results?

Answer (score -7):

It's interesting that 7 artists appear to stand alone in the linked word cloud from [Music for Focus While Coding](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#work-_-music-for-focus-while-coding):

- Alan Walker
- Arijit Singh
- Imagine Dragons
- Linkin Park
- Ludovico Einaudi
- Taylor Swift
- Two Steps from Hell

The [How Technologies Are Connected](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#technology-_-how-technologies-are-connected) word cloud was interesting as always. The [Why Don't Developers Participate on Stack Overflow?](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#community-_-why-dont-developers-participate-on-stack-overflow) one was... underwhelming.

Comment: I was one of the people who included Two Steps from Hell in my survey results along with Audiomachine. Aside from that I think I only put "Classical"