# No browser title for the Developer Survey Results 2019 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, survey-2019

There is no browser title set for the Developer Survey Results 2019 page. When I clicked the developer survey Google Ad from the side bar, in the opened window's browser title I can see the Google Ad URL, this is not looking good.

> [image: Google Ad]
>
> [image: From Google Ad]

Also If I navigate the survey result from [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/04/09/the-2019-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results-are-in) or the [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382647/), there also I can see the URL in the browser title.

> [image: From Blog]

In the [Developer Survey Results 2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) page, the browser title was set properly.

> [image: Developer Survey Results 2018]

**So can be the browser title corrected, when navigate from multiple resources.**

Comment: Sniped me by 22 minutes :)

Comment: I'd say its a feature request, not a bug ;)

Comment: @Luuklag The feature was added in last year's page, and not added this year, so bug ;)

Comment: Haven't you heard? [Browser titles are out of style now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live/381672#381672).

Comment: Title added back!