# What is with "Thanks" in the developers' perspectives by gender section of the survey results?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019, gender

Reading the results, and related to [another discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382683/has-so-ever-asked-professional-female-developers-about-what-they-think-of-so/382695?noredirect=1#comment686561_382695) I found the results on [Developers' perspectives by gender](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019#community-_-developers-perspectives-by-gender) a bit confusing by the way it is represented, and perhaps by the way it was analysed.

It states that women used the words:

- Condescending
- Replies
- Nicer
- Rude
- Dumb
- Friendlier
- A**holes
- Thanks
- Confusing
- Knowing

about 3 to 5 times as much as men in the survey to refer to some part of Stack Overflow they want to see changed. This is a clear signal to me that there is something going on with the way women and man communicate differently.

For most of the terms, I can guesstimate the message of a sentence it was used in:

- *less* Condescending *replies*
- *less condescending/rude* Replies
- *be* Nicer
- *be less* Rude
- Dumb
- *be more* Friendlier
- *we want less* A**holes
- Thanks
- Confusing
- Knowing

Most of this makes perfect sense to me, and for some I can't really come up with a good example of a sentence right now. But I wonder what is up with the **Thanks** part? Is there anyone who can enlighten me; perhaps someone from the team? What is the context this "thanks" is used in?

Comment: Saying "Thanks" is frowned upon on SO as it's considered noise, I'm guessing they don't like that and want it to change

Comment: @George, that was one of my guesses too, but I'd love to have a more founded answer

Comment: Without further information, it might just as well be _we want more a**holes_, _more condescending replies_, etc. I find that the perspective thing says very, very little with how it's expressed there. Unless we have more context about how these words are used it's just a guess

Comment: @ErikA that could, technically, be a possibility but I find it so unlikely that I assumed the opposite. However for some the plausibility of less/more is not so distinct hence I'd like some more detail behind this.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify what the results are showing. That *may* make it a bit easier to understand what the survey is getting across. The way it was written in this question made it sound like women use those words during regular use, when in actuality they used those words in their survey responses *to describe a change to SO they would like to see*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm the data scientist who worked on the survey, and I can confirm what a commenter above suggested. Women were more likely to say one thing they would like to change about Stack Overflow is users being able to say thanks to each other.

[image]

To clarify a bit about this graph, it shows words that are more and less likely to be used by different groups. For example, **more** men than women said Stack Overflow users should be able to say thanks but this graph is about relative use, not total frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Julia. And hey, I said thanks. Lets wait for a "noize" flag ;)

Comment: Hi Julia, I applaud your work, but boiling 'Developers' Perspectives By Gender' down to single words was ambiguous and not actionable. Could you resummarize the items by sentence? e.g. *"Allow question asker to say thanks to answerers [in comments?/ as a new feature?/ a feature that generate a private message, as on Quora?]"*, ditto what is the expanded summary for Condescending, Replies, Nicer, Dumb... As to *"Allow question asker to say thanks to answerers"*, how do we convert that into an actionable change request, given it would generate a lot of comments, and SO policy discourages that?

Comment: @smci The actionable point I take from this plot is that not everyone I interact with here on our site brings the same perceptions or priorities to it. As far as saying thanks, there aren't currently policy or product changes planned for how we say thanks, but we have used insight from the survey to guide changes before and personally I think it's something that could be on the table. Is there a way to let users express normal human reactions like thanks to each other in a way that doesn't distract other users with many noisy comments? Probably.

Comment: I wonder if this is actually due to inherent gender differences, or due to the fact that women are underrepresented on Stack Overflow and thus less familiar with our unique model than the male respondents. Do you see this same correlation when you control for experience with the site? In other words, do women who are experienced SO users still tend to express a greater desire to say “thanks” relative to men with comparable SO experience? (I know that might be hard to tease out because of limited sample sizes…)

Comment: My personal opinion is that the upvote is the ultimate expression of "thanks". I think it's important to be mindful of all users of SO (including guests) whose primary reason for landing on a given page is for the answer. Even though saying "thanks" is nice, and we all appreciate hearing that word, it can become real noise (and perhaps frustrating) to someone reading the answer page for the first time. What would we think of Wikipedia or Quora, for example, if we saw "thanks" and "love it" after every paragraph?

Comment: @CodyGray While I generally disagree with the "let's redecorate for females" tendency this is one area where I believe I can shed some light. On the whole, as a group, women work more towards ensuring a harmonious environment (YMMV <g>). I don't know how much is genetic and how much comes from up-bringing. "Non-essential politeness" in society is actually essential for achieving this, whether we're consciously aware of it or not. Personally I see nothing wrong with newbies saying "Thanks" in a comment, and when they do I'll usually take a moment to delete it so that it dosn't clutter the site.

Comment: @CodyGray ...NOT using "Thanks" and other politnesses is a conscious decision by this community and goes against the grain of what humans have learned that they need in order to get along in large groups. That's OK, here, but needs to be learned. And it's not just women, BTW, who have problems with this, but also members of highly structured societies.

Comment: As a woman who said this, it's not that I'm inexperienced (and isn't it interesting how someone - a moderator, no less - assumed that the reason was "Women just aren't familiar with the site") but that I think the effect on newcomers of seeing their posts edited to remove basic courtesy is worse than the effect on the community of not having to see an occasional "Thanks."  Better to let people learn by observation to see that it's not a community norm than to actively edit what people see as basic courtesy out of their posts, IMO.

Comment: @RichS I feel social gratification from helping people several times a day, when I'm notified that someone has upvoted my posts. It's a very good feeling, and we aren't cluttering the site for *hundreds of other people* who view the posts without upvoting. It's win-win-win! :)

Comment: As a long-time user of the site, I always got the impression that the "No Thanks" was more of a "The question should primarily concern the technical details, not the story of the person asking."  It's not so much the "Thanks" being disliked as the "I've read everything I could, and tried a dozen different things, and I'm totally confused now!  Any help would be appreciated!" closing paragraphs.  But my perspective on this may be limited by my own experience.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler, I tried everything is essential information, as long as you state exactly what you tried and WHY something didn't work. If you state it in general like you did you probably just did a lousy job at googling.

Comment: In the Red/Blue/Green/Yellow model for personalities (there are several won't go into the various ones - popular in corporate settings to hone communication skills) Greens place a high priority on social interaction and recognition, and Reds place a high priority on brevity and efficiency in communication. I suspect woman are over proportionally Green, and men are over proportionately Red. StackOverflow has always been more Red oriented (and heavily Blue of course as well which is all about analysis).

Comment: @MikeWise interesting point. Perhaps a good question for the next survey? Julia could you write this down already?